# How to connect Windows Ubuntu20.04 LTS to my Xming server

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, xming

I want to be able to use gedit from my windows 10 machine, but I can't get my Ubuntu20.04 LTS app to open any displays over my xming server.

I know the Xming server is set up because it shows up in the bottom left of my task bar and reads "Xming Server:0.0" when I over mouse over it. I've tried these commands for exporting my display:

```
 - export DISPLAY="`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver//'`:0"
 - export DISPLAY=:0
 - export DISPLAY=0.0
```

but when I try to run gedit it always throws an error like this

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:511): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:44:04.133: cannot open display: :0.0
```

except the `12:44:04.133` address changes every time, and the display changes with the variable.

Is there something else that needs configuring that I missed or could this possibly be a network issue?
Any help would be appreciated.